# Is there any way of making company show local classes inside a Java project?

Tags: company-mode, lsp-mode, java

I have a configuration for Java code on emacs that's the following:

```el
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :config
  (global-flycheck-mode))

(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :hook (after-init . global-company-mode)
  :config
  (setq company-tooltip-align-annotations t
        company-minimum-prefix-length 1
        company-idle-delay 0.0)
  (with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
    (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook #'company-mode))
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-capf))

(use-package lsp-java
  :ensure t
  :hook (java-mode . lsp)
  :config
  (customize-set-variable 'lsp-java-server-install-dir "~/Documents/jdt-language-server/")
  (require 'lsp-java))
```

It works fine with the flycheck for errors and the company mode shows recommendations of functions in *Java*. I'm using the [*Eclipse JDT* language server (Milestone build 1.9.0)](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.jdt.ls/downloads):

[image]

However, it doesn't recognize classes that I create in my project, so I'm not able to type and see recommendations of the classes and functions I have developed in my project. Am I missing any detail in my configuration? I've started to think that the language server I'm using in *Java* doesn't have this functionality since it works pretty fine with the *TypeScript* language server that I'm using... Is there any way of making *Company* recommend to me *Java* classes from my *Java* project?

Comment: I suppose the first step would be to report the problem to Eclipse.

Comment: Then, while you're waiting for a response, you could either try grouping `company-dabbrev-code` with `company-capf` to add all-symbols-in-all-buffers completions, or write a new backend of your own. Maybe search around for existing reports in lsp-java, etc.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks! I didn't manage to create a new backend but grouping `company-dabbrev-code` with `company-campf` worked fine for me. Even though it works only when the file I want recommendations is open in a buffer. In practice, I only changed the last line of the `use-package company` to `  (add-to-list 'company-backends `(company-capf :with company-dabbrev-code)))`